# How to set delete button in li element right side top?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am trying to make li element with delete button but i am not able find a solutions

want i want is :

[image]

here **red rectangle is delete button**

html what is trying is :

```
 <li id="liRightDescriptions">
    <span>
    Descriptions
    <img src="../Images/RemoveButton.ico">
    </span>
    </li>
```

More : i need to show **delete button on MouseOver** and when i click there jquery query event should fired, and on **text** also,

so i guess, i dont want to set delete image as background

**This is my html** :  http://jsfiddle.net/2h78A/

Answer (score 1):

HTML (can replace x in span with any text or image)

```
<ul>
<li><span>x</span>Text 1</li>
<li><span>x</span>Text 1</li>
<li><span>x</span>Text 1</li>
<li><span>x</span>Text 1</li>
<li><span>x</span>Text 1</li>
<li><span>x</span>Text 1</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{
    width:160px;
}
li{
    position:relative;
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:#ccc;
    border-radius:3px;
    margin:3px;
}
li:hover span{display:block;}
li span{
    display:none;
    padding:3px;
    line-height:8px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the button position use:

```
.removeImg {
    float: right;
}
```

or

```
.liRightDescriptions span {
    position: relative;
}

.removeImg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

To show/hide on hover:

```
$('.liRightDescriptions').hover(function() {
    $('.removeImg').fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
    $('.removeImg').fadeOut(500);
});
```

To hide the `li` on click:

```
$('.removeImg').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.liRightDescriptions').hide(500);
    /* you could also remove the element altogether here if needed */
});
```

Note you should be using classes and not id's as the elements are not unique.

Comment: You could do this without JS. `#liRightDescriptions img { display: none; }` then `#liRightDescriptions:hover img { display: block; }`

Comment: Easier to use JS as they also want to hide it on click

Comment: could you able to change here, please?

Comment: to much space between text and image :P

Comment: Well you need to style the width to your liking.

Answer (score -1):

```
black-square {
position: relative
}

delete-img { 
position:absolute;
top:2px;
right: 2px;
}
```

Comment: `black-square` and `delete-img` are not valid CSS selectors.

Comment: And that is why you put -1? User can adapt the selectors as "black-square" and "delete-img" are pretty obvious page elements if you look to the image provided

Comment: Also the fact that you state `left:2px;` and `right: 2px;` which together mean your code doesn't answer the question correctly.

Comment: That's a real mistake, you should have put it in your first comment or, better yet, been constructive and tell me to edit as you realize it was a mistake right? answer edited, now it works and answer the question correctly. If it's not correctly, at least gave to the user an idea on how to solve it